# Concatenar dos correos

Tags: jquery

estoy trabajando con un módulo de prestashop y quiero realizar una modificación, quiero agregar el correo de mi tienda desde el código, se ejecuta cuando un cliente se manda una cotización a su correo, pero de manera oculta quiero que también me llegue ese correo a mi cuenta, estaba viendo la forma de concatenarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
var email_tienda = 'correo@tienda.com';
var email_addresses = $email_tienda + ',' + $("#cqw-email-popup input[name='cqw-emails']").val();
```

pero al hacer eso no me funciona, no me manda los correos :( agradecería mucho su apoyo, gracias

```
var email_tienda = 'correo@tienda.com';
    var email_addresses = $("#cqw-email-popup input[name='cqw-emails']").val();
    var url = MPTools.joinUrl(module_ajax_url_cqw, 'route=cqwfrontcartcontroller&action=processemailquote&rand=' + new Date().getTime());

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        //dataType: "json",
        data: {
            'id_cqw_quote' : id_cqw_quote,
            'email_addresses' : email_addresses
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $.fancybox.close();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Qué significa que no funciona? Qué error obtienes?

Comment: el codigo como texto por favor, esto facilitara ayudarte :)

Comment: @christian si, disculpa

Comment: @Alfabravo como tal no me manda ningún error, simplemente no se envían los correos pero si dejo la variable normal si lo envía, me refiero a que se quede de ésta manera ´ var email_addresses = $("#cqw-email-popup input[name='cqw-emails']").val();´  si lo dejo así sí se envía normal

Comment: te recomiendo que todo el codigo para enviar el correo lo pongas en una funcion, y creas un arreglo con el email de tu cliente y el tuyo, luego lo recorres y en cada iteracion ejecutas la funcion (codigo para enviar el email)

Comment: Hm, yo revisaría la documentación de cómo espera los parámetros esa URL. Es posible que una cadena separada por comas no baste y esté esperando un JSON, algo así. En teoría, si fuese un servidor SMTP común y corriente, tu aproximación serviría perfectamente sin hacer un envío completo por cada email. Como hay un controller ahí delante del servicio de envío de emails, no sabemos cómo lee ese campo email_addresses. Revísalo